# Node.js client vs. server - same code different results

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I have the following code on the client and on the server but it is giving me different results.  The code on the client is correct.

The code:

```
var Query = Parse.Object.extend("ParseTable");
var query = new Parse.Query(query);
query.equalTo("user", {
            __type: "Pointer",
            className: "_User",
            objectId: ID
        });
query.find().then(function (object) {
//where//object = [child] = [{user: child}]

var testObject = _.map(object, function (a) {
                console.log("inside testObject", a.get("user").id);
               //correctly shows 'someId' on both the server and client!

               return _.extend(_.find(a), {sTId: a.id}, {mId: a.get("user").id});});

               //where//testObject = [{user:child, sTId: 'abc123', mId: 'someId'}];
               console.log( _.first(testObject).mId);//'someId' on the client and 
               //'undefined' on the server});
```

I'm lost as to what I'm doing wrong and I have no one but the SO community to help. Thanks.

Comment: Which are the different results and how can we test this on our own ?

Comment: @Marged I don't know how I can help you test it, sorry.  This code worked before and is just now breaking in testing.  I'm trying to figure out what could be wrong but my bet is that it's something idiosyncratic and it is with this in mind that I'm reaching out to the community.  Maybe a suggestion of someone that seen something like this in the past?  Could this have something to do with Parse.com security settings?

Comment: All we are asking for is some test data because not everyone will be able to tell you the problem only from looking at the code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Marged, thanks for your persistence. I tried to add some more detail. Let me know what else you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above has been working for a long time and for reasons still unknown to me I can't get it to work. I decided to move on though by using the following solution to 'testObject' above.

```
var Query = Parse.Object.extend("ParseTable");
var query = new Parse.Query(query);
query.equalTo("user", {
            __type: "Pointer",
            className: "_User",
            objectId: ID
        });
query.first().then(function (object) {//notice first instead of find at the end of the query!

var testObject = {};
testObject.sTId = object.id;
testObject.mId = object.get("user").id;
testObject.user = object.get("user");
})
```

This ends up a better solution anyway, nice clean and easier to read!